# Finding the probability that in ten dice throws the digit six will appear at least five times

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Find the probability that in ten dice throws the digit six will appear at least five times.

My attempt:

Using complement, six will appear at most 4 times.

I'm pretty sure that $1-(\frac 5 6)^4$ isn't right since it doesn't account for six appearing 3, 2, 1, 0 times. So using inclusion exclusion:

Six not appearing: $(\frac 5 6 )^4$

Six appearing once: $\frac 1 6 \cdot  (\frac 5 6 )^3 $

Six appearing twice: $(\frac 1 6 \cdot \frac 5 6 )^2$

Six appearing three times: $(\frac 1 6)^3 \cdot \frac 5 6 $

Six appearing four times: $(\frac 1 6) ^4$

Calculating the above with inclusion exclusion: $1-( (5/6)^4 -(1/6)*(5/6)^3+(5/36)^2 - (1/6)^3*(5/6) + (1/6)^4 )=0.59799382716$

Now when I wrote this I noticed the complement and the given case are symmetric, the only difference between them is the case where six appearing exactly 5 times, so I tried to plug it into the calculator and got a very similar result: $1-(5/6)^5=0.59812242798$.

Are either of them correct? Why do we subtract the middle point from the general case in the symmetric approach?

Comment: You are dealing with binomial distribution here. Are you familiar with it? Your calculations are not correct.

Comment: @drhab no we haven't covered binomial distribution yet.

Comment: It is very good in general to use symmetry, but there really is not symmetry here. Note that the probability of exactly $k$ $6$'s is $\binom{10}{k}(1/6)^k(5/6)^{10-k}$.

Comment: the main mistake here seems to be that you have not counted how many ways there are to get each overall results, e.g. there is 1 way to gegt no sixrs, there are 10 ways to get a single 6 and so on... you'll need the binomial coefficients $^nC_r$

Comment: @AndréNicolas so the calculation is the same (inclusion exclusion) but I just need to add the corresponding binomial to each of the summands?

Comment: We add the terms mentioned in my comment, from $k=5$ to $k=10$.  Your calculation omitted the binomial coefficients, and the exponents were wrong,  The fact one tosses $10$ times was not used at all.  Wrong analysis from the start.

Comment: @kuhaku That is strange. Binomial distribution is mostly (one of) the first distribution(s) that receives attention in courses about probability.

Comment: We saw it with inclusion exclusion but they didn't call it binomial distribution, just "how many ways there are for this possibility" or something along those lines. @drhab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $10$ independent experiments here that all have a chance $\frac16$ to succeed (i.e. a six is thrown). If $X$ denotes the number of successes then it has [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n=10$ and $p=\frac16$. That determines its PMF (probability mass function): $$P(X=k)=\binom{10}{k}\left(\frac16\right)^k\left(\frac56\right)^{10-k}$$

To be found here is $$P(X\geq5)=P(X=5)+\cdots+P(X=10)$$

Comment: Is $P(X≥5)=1-P(X<5)$?

Comment: Yes. So you can also compute $1-[P(X=0)+\cdots+P(X=4)]$ (only one calculation less, so unfortunately not much gain here).